# Why is this error occurring, and how do I improve this function

Tags: javascript

```
function addElement(tag, content, location){
    var getTag = document.createElement(tag);
    var getContent = document.createTextNode(content);
    var getLocation = document.getElementsByClassName(location);
    getTag.appendChild(getContent);
    document.getElementsByClassName(location).appendChild(getTag);
}
addElement("p","Hello World","div");
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: `document.getElementsByClassName(...).appendChild` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName() returns an HTMLCollection. If you want to append it in only one place, you can do;

```
document.getElementsByClassName(location)[0].appendChild(getTag);
```

Or if you want to append it to multiple places (all the places which have 'location' class), you can do it inside a loop.

```
for(i = 0; i < getLocation.length; i++) {
    getLocation[i].appendChild(getTag);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object that does not have `appendChild` method.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(location)[0].appendChild(getTag);
```

or

```
getLocation[0].appendChild(getTag);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change this line from
`document.getElementsByClassName(location).appendChild(getTag);`

to

`document.getElementsByClassName(location)[0].appendChild(getTag);`

Credit to nikhil for similar answer

Comment: By the time i could post this (because my account got banned and unbanned) you guys had already solved the problem. Good job Hope some of these answers work-although others have this answer already, it was not  copied from this thread